What is the bug in this function that converts a hexatridecimal number (passed as a char) to a unsigned? How does one fix it?
I've been reading to the book Modern C by Jens Gustedt and on section 8.4, that present C library functions that deals with string processing and conversion, there is a piece of code in which is defined a function that converts a single char (using its int value) that represent a number on a hexatridecimal (36) base to its decimal equivalent. This function is supposed to explain how part of <stdlib.h>'s strtoul function works.
Here is the code presented:
/* Supposes that lowercase characters are contiguous. */
static_assert('z'-'a' == 25,
                "alphabetic characters not contiguous");
#include <ctype.h>
/* Converts an alphanumeric digit to an unsigned */
/* '0' ... '9'  =>  0 ..  9u */
/* 'A' ... 'Z'  => 10 .. 35u */
/* 'a' ... 'z'  => 10 .. 35u */
/* Other values =>   Greater */
unsigned hexatridecimal(int a) {
        if (isdigit(a)) {
                /* This is guaranteed to work: decimal digits
                   are consecutive, and isdigit is not
                   locale dependent. */
                return a - '0';
        } else {
                /* Leaves a unchanged if it not lowercase */
                a = toupper(a);
                /* Returns value >= 36 if not Latin uppercase */
                return (isupper(a)) ? 10 + (a - 'A') : -1;
        }
}

The thing is, to convert an alphabet letter to a decimal value it uses (a - 'A'), where a represent the letter being converted. About this operation, the author proceeds with this:

The second return hexatridecimal  makes an assumption about the relation between a and 'A'. What is it?

Describe an error scenario in which this assumption is not fulfilled.

Fix this bug: that is, rewrite the code such that it makes no assumption about the relation between a and 'A'.


Now, I don't know if I let some crucial piece of information fly past me or if I'm missing something else, but I can't figure something out for point number 2 and 3.
For the first point I suppose the assumption is a is greater or equal to 'A'. Since that is what is required to produce correct values according to the comment above the function. The thing is, by using the static_assert at the beginning of the code and the ternary operator at the return line, with isupper(a) as the condition, I can't see it happening and therefore don't know what to argue about the second point. Therefore, I'm also stuck at the third point.
Is the assumption something different from what I supposed? What is the bug in this, when would it lead to an error and how does one fix it?

The expression a - 'A' depends on an encoding where all upper-case letters are in a contiguous range, like it is for ASCII. The C specification does not assume ASCII, and there are other encodings still in use where letters are encoded in non-contiguous ways. Like for example EBCDIC. To solve the problem you need to use some kind of lookup table that maps a character to a number.

I find it amusing that the author does an assert on the lower case characters, then proceeds to use the upper case characters for conversion.   You could create a very long switch statement with a case for each value (e.g. case 'z': { return 35; }).  This would make no assumptions about the relation of a and 'A'.   But unless you are planning on porting to an EBCDIC machine, it's quite safe to make the relationship assumption.

@BradLanam They apparently assume that either both cases are contiguous or neither is. Which is probably a reasonable assumption.

And that's likely the the error scenario suggested in question 2.

The question is confused by using the function argument name a which has nothing to do with 'a' or 'A'. I suggest renaming it to sth like ch.

Now I see how an error could appear. I assumed upper case would also be contiguous if the lower case is confirmed to be, as @Barmar suggested the author did. About the fix though, wouldn't it be simpler to just change toupper to tolower, isupper to islower and 'A' to 'a'?

That still doesn't fix the situation where neither case is contiguous.

Note that isdigit(a) is guaranteed to work regardless of whether digits are encoded consecutively (although the C Standard states they must be). As do isalpha() etc. which take account of the character encoding scheme.

You can either use a lookup table (like a big switch/case) or char *alphabet = "ABCDE...Z"; and then use strchr() to get the character position.

@Barmar in that case the code wouldn't compile due to the static_assert. Unless there's some character encoding in which the characters are not contiguous but 'z'-'a' == 25. I mean, I don't doubt one exists and if one does I would be very curious to see it.

You're supposed to remove that assertion when you rewrite the code to remove the assumption.

You are at liberty to invent one, such as the sequence ayc... xbz and write your own compiler.

Sounds reasonable. I like the solution using char *alphabet and strchr(). Many thanks!


The second return hexatridecimal makes an assumption about the relation between a and 'A'. What is it?

It assumes that all characters 'A' to 'Z' as well as 'a' to 'z' are stored adjacently in alphabetical order in the symbol table. But in fact the C language makes no guarantees of any of that, which is probably what Gustedt wants to point out.
There is for example the horror story of an ancient symbol table called EBCDIC where this isn't true. That one is supposedly still skulking about in very old IBM systems, or at least "language lawyers" love to scream "But what about EBCDIC!" whenever the topic of character to digit conversion pops up.
The only characters that are guaranteed by C to be stored adjacently are '0' to '9'.


Describe an error scenario in which this assumption is not fulfilled.

EBCDIC!


Fix this bug: that is, rewrite the code such that it makes no assumption about the relation between a and 'A'.

You could slam in a bunch of static asserts etc for sure but then what if they fail? You wouldn't be able to use the function then. And alternatively, writing a bunch of run-time checks will slow down the code a lot.
But besides that, the implementation in the book is naive in itself and could be improved in many ways. It turns out that we can fix performance and conversion problems in one go. A common way to implement fast symbol digit to integer conversion is to use a look-up table:
unsigned hexatridecimal(int a)
{
  static const int LOOKUP [127] = 
  {
    ['0'] = 0,
    ['1'] = 1,
    /* ... */

    ['A'] = 10,
    ['B'] = 11,
    /* ... */

    ['a'] = 10,
    ['b'] = 11,
    /* ... */
  };

  return LOOKUP[a];
}

This sacrifices 127*sizeof(int) bytes of read-only memory at the benefit of very fast conversion. The character value is used as an index to the look-up table array where the value to convert to is stored. No run-time calculations, branches or slow calls to ctype.h functions are required.
The magic number 127 comes from the classic ASCII table (or UTF8) holding 127 printable characters, although the 32 lowest ones are non-printable. The beauty of over-allocating room for all manner of invalid characters is that when something is omitted from the LOOKUP initializer list because there was no initializer, that index will get set to zero.
Error handling to prevent out of range numbers should probably be added, so that we know that the variable is in range 0 <= a < 127.
Also notably there's no reason why we couldn't use the above lookup table to support all manner of bases from base 2 up to base 36 and use the same function for all of them, including the most common ones: binary, octal, decimal, hex.

Did you mean to use CHAR_MAX + 1 rather than 127?

@pmg Not really. This could be expanded to the highly desired EBCDIC compatibility by going up to 255. The parameter could have been made unsigned char though.

Pedantic: issues exist when a is not a valid digit as it may get converted as a valid digit or cause UB.

Prone to failure with a negative
hexatridecimal(int a) could readily get called as char ch = ....; hexatridecimal(ch); as isdigit(a) is UB with a negative a unless a == EOF.
To fix:
unsigned hexatridecimal(int a) {
    if (a == EOF) { return TBD_VALUE;
    if (isdigit((unsigned char) a)) {

Locale
a = toupper(a); is a problem when a is some extended ASCII character (e.g. not 0-127) that maps to 'A' - 'Z' like 'ç' might map to a 'C' when 'Ç' is not in the locale.
Non-sequential A=Z
Well covered by @Lundin.  Although I would use
static_assert(UCHAR_MAX <= 1023, ""Reconsider for large bits/char"); 

unsigned hexatridecimal(int a) {
  static const unsigned char LOOKUP [UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {
    ['0'] = 0, ['1'] = 1, /* ... */
    ['A'] = 10, ['B'] = 11, /* ... */
    ['a'] = 10, ['b'] = 11, /* ... */
  };

  return LOOKUP[(unsigned char)a];
}

Maybe something more to handle EOF like other is... functions.
